# "Are you" or "you are"

Tags: questions-v-relatives

I don't understand the following question:

> And can you tell me where you’re from?

Why is "where **you are** from" used instead of "where **are you** from"?

Comment: You could say it the way you suggest, but it would be punctuated differently: _And can you tell me: Where are you from?_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Where are you from?* is a question. The auxiliary verb<sup>†</sup> *are* "inverts" or changes places with its subject, *you*.

*Can you tell me . . .?* is also a question, and likewise has subject/auxiliary inversion: *can* inverts with *you*. But then you go on to specify *X*, the object of the verb *tell*, the matter you want your hearer to tell you. For that you don't use another question but a *fused relative clause*<sup>‡</sup>, which is **not** a question and does **not** have subject/inversion.

---

<sup>†</sup> *BE* always behaves like an auxiliary, even when it is the only verb in the clause.

<sup>‡</sup> This is sometimes called a *free relative clause*. It is constructed just like an ordinary relative clause (a *bound* relative clause), but acts as a noun phrase  rather than as a modifier.

Answer (score 0):

It is used because there is already a question before the *where*.

Here is a related question and answer:

[“Do you know what IS IT?” vs “Do you know what IT IS?”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/do-you-know-what-is-it-vs-do-you-know-what-it-is)